# is the phrase "available with me" correct?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

I used a bus in which the hostess said that the company magazine is available with me on demand. Is the usage of *available* along with *with* correct?

Comment: Why would it not be correct? What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: shouldnt it be avail yourselves with a magazine?

Comment: Why would "available *with* me" be wrong?

Comment: i dont know didnt sound ok.

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @kris Why - do you come free with the magazine? Or how's this: "The ice cream is available with the kiosk" ? :)

Comment: @Araucaria You apparently have preconcieved notions about "available with" or even about "available" itself. You really meant just a smiley or ;) ?

Answer (score 1):

*Available **[to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available%20*%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cavailable%20%2A%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bavailable%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20from%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20leads%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20by%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20before%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20in%20me%3B%2Cc0)** me*, seems like the most common expression in the written corpus, if she is referring to herself, but she is probably intending to say:

> I have the company magazine *available for **you*** on demand.

Her grammar is awkward but intelligible as the implied phrase is intuitive:

> The company magazine is available (to you) with me on demand.

She could say it more clearly:

> The company magazine is available **from** me on demand.
>   or
>   The company magazine is available **through** me on demand.

Comment: can you send me a sentence from any book using this phrase

Comment: [Sample](https://books.google.com/books?id=jZidBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&dq=%22available+to+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H5ARVfePL7bLsAS0iYH4Bg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22available%20to%20me%22&f=false)

Comment: yeah that is correct

Answer (score 1):

If the hostess actually said

> "The company magazine is available **with me** on demand."

Then that is indeed a non-standard use of *with*; normal use would call for either *from* or *through*.  (The use of "with" implies that the magazine and the hostess are a combined unit; if you request the magazine, you also get the hostess.  And that is probably not the case.)

Comment: ;) yeah thats definitely not the case

Comment: but i think its clear. next time she says it ill tell her not to use this line.

Comment: I might also accept "available by me," but not "with.